# What is the Witching Hour?

Tags: team-fortress-2

From the wiki update today:

> - Added New Halloween Map Helltower Equip a spell book and cast spells against your enemies
> - Spells can be found by pushing the cart, killing enemies and during the **Witching hour**
> - The Clocktower contains powerful magic during the **Witching hour** Win the race to start mega healed in the final battle for your prize

What it seems like is that there is literally no mention of what the "witching hour" actually is.  What exactly happens during the Witching hour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Witching Hour is an event that happens every now and then where the clock tower beyond the pit of Helltower rings. When it does, two etheral paths temporarily appear so players can walk across the pit and reach the base of the clock tower, where they can collect a rare spell and warp back to their spawnroom with a speed and health buff. Getting a rare spell in this way earns an achievement.